# Problemas al utilizar modo estricto react

Tags: javascript

Quiero mostrar un mensaje de error y que al pasar unos segundos desaparezca, para ello utilizo el siguiente codigo.

```
export const useTextError = () => {
    const { error } = useSelector((state) => state.login);
    const [textError, setTextError] = useState('')
    

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!error) return;
        setTextError('Correo electrónico o contraseña invalidos')
        
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
          setTextError('')
        }, 2500);
        
        return () => {
          clearTimeout(timer);
        };
      }, [error]);


    return textError;
}
```

Funciona bien, sin modo estricto pero al ponerlo en modo estrico ya no se muestra el mensaje de error.

El error lo traigo del store, estoy utilizando redux toolkit y react 18.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    isAuth:false,
    error:false 
}

const loginSlice = createSlice({
    name:'login',
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        loginPending: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = action.payload;
        },
        loginSuccess: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isAuth = true; 
            state.error = false;   
        },
        loginFail: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isAuth = false;
            state.error = action.payload;
        }
    }
})

const {reducer, actions} = loginSlice;

export const {loginPending, loginSuccess, loginFail} = actions;

export default reducer;
```

Tengo otros efectos que dependen de alguna condicion de las variables de estado de redux y tampoco funcionan, pero si utilizo efectos que no dependen de redux funcionan normalmente.
El initialState del error esta en falso y nunca se actualiza ni modifica en el modo estricto.

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Si al poner `"use strict"` no funciona debe ser porque hay un error de sintaxis

Comment: Por consola no hay errores, y en las react dev tools al mirar si cambia el estado con modo estricto nunca cambia se queda siempre en falso. Si saco el modo estricto los estados se actualizan correctamente, y los efectos funcionan.

Comment: Estuve haciendo pruebas, con solo un contador y no se actualiza el valor en el estado, por ende no renderiza nada nuevo. Asi que el problema esta en algo que este haciendo mal con redux o no se si sera por versiones.